# Automatically provisioning a Windows Server at OVH

Tags: windows, provisioning, ovh

I'd like to automatically run a script to provision Windows Servers when I set them up as Dedicated Servers at OVH.

I see that they have an option for an `Installation script (URL)`], but how do I use it for Windows?

[[image: OVH console's option for an Installation script]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From watching a Windows Server boot in OVH's Remote KVM, I see that the last thing OVH does is run a .cmd file from a zip.

[image: Screenshot of OVH Boot Config Process]

So after testing it, I found that you must:

- Provide a URL to a `.zip` file for the `Installation script (URL)`
- Containing a batch file ending in the extension `.cmd`
- Which will get run as Admin as the last setup step
- And will output its results to `c:\ovhupd\script\customerscriptlog.txt`

You can also provide any other supporting files you want, as long as they don't end in `.cmd`

> ***Protip:***  Run `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the beginning of your `.cmd` script to change directory to where your script is